# RxSwift, How to apply back-pressure to serially display a UIAlertView for each item in a Stream

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have an `Observable<Item>` that emits a series of items asynchronously. For each Item in the stream I need to display a UIAlertView. Each time the user dismisses the alert (if there is a new item) I need to grab the next item and show a new alert for it.

The problem I have is that the Observable emits items too quickly. While an alert is displayed, several items are emitted and I lose that information.

The stream might produce 10 items in one second, and I want to show 10 popups, that will be opened serially, one at a time, one after the other.

Is there a way to consume the next item in the stream only once I am ready to display the alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

Take 2 Observables:

1. Your existing Observable that emits a value as you described in your answer.
2. An Observable that emits a value whenever the user dismisses the alert view.

Then use the `zip` combination operator to create a third Observable out of this 2 Observables. Because of the `zip` operator this third Observable only emits a value when Observable 1 and Observable 2 both emit a value. In other words it emits a value when there is an event in your stream and the user dismissed the previous alert. Everytime the third (zipped) Observable emits a value you show an alert.

Here is an image on how the `zip` operator works (stolen from the fabulous [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/)):

[image]

In this image the **first line** is your stream. The **second line** is the user dismissing the alert view. The **third line** is the signal to show the next alert.

You can see that while alert **(1A)** is shown there are two more values emitted in your stream (**(2)** and **(3)**). The zipping takes care that the next event on the third line is only emitted when the user dismisses the alert **(B)**. Then the zipping "grabs" the next event from your stream and emits **(2B)** on the third line. Which causes the next alert to be shown.

To make this work you have to start the "alert dismissed" Observable with one event **(A)**. Because otherwise the `zip` will wait for the first alert to be dismissed before it fires its first event.

In code it would look something like this. (I simply used an `Observable<Int>` to simulate your stream). The `didDismissedAlert` Observable is of type `Observable<Void>`:

```
Observable.zip(stream, didDismissAlert.startWith(())) { (streamValue, _) -> Int in
        return streamValue
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { streamValue in
        // showAlert with the value from the stream
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had to use a publish subject to be able to push the next tap using onNext. Is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/RyogaK/41f55c88250d5882f0e7d10240c4c866